# What is this lever for on the lens mount? (F-mount, not aperture lever)

Tags: nikon, lens-mount, tokina

This is the photo of the lens mount of an F-mount Tokina 10-17 mm (taken from online).  What is the lever that I marked in red for?  Note that this is not the aperture lever (which you can also see on the bottom right).

[image]

Comment: [Here's another photo I found.](http://digitalphotographylive.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Tokina-10-17mm-f3.5-4.5-AT-X-107-AF-DX-NH-Fisheye-Lens-Mount.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra lever is the "Maximum Aperture Indexing Lever" or "Lens Speed Indexing Lever". It was added on some AI-S lenses to transmit the maximum aperture information to the camera body.

It was only used on FA & F4 camera bodies for more accurate automatic multi-pattern metering.

Comment: ...and Tokina appears to have chosen to use a metal tab on their F mounts that can be adjusted to suit different lenses in their lineup, rather than die casting a different rigid mount for each lens type. An economical design decision.